# Explanation needed for the in_addr strcuture

Tags: c++, struct, winsock, data-members

I do not understand [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366055(v=vs.85).aspx) for it's member's at all. It ask for things I've never done before like the `S_un_b` member needs `The IPv4 address of the host formatted as four u_chars.` which doesn't really make sense to me unless it means something like type casting but I don't think that's it. Any examples, documentation, hints, tips, etc would be very greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The IPv4 address of the host formatted as four u_chars

means that the host address in IPv4 format (*eg* `209.81.97.0`) is stored as 4 consecutive `unsigned char`s each being 8 bits wide.

Comment: What about the other member `S_un_w The IPv4 address of the host formatted as two u_shorts.`

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen that would use 2 consecutive 16-bit `unsigned short`s for the 32-bit IPv4 host address

Comment: I honestly have no clue.

Comment: Note that since it is a union, you only need to set one or the other, not both.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I didn't know what that meant. XD